# how to configure HTML purifier to allow "callto:123" in an anchor href value?

Tags: htmlpurifier

Can someone point me to what it will take to allow an anchor tag like this to pass through htmlpurifier, untouched? :

```
<a href="callto:+1-800-555-1212" class="callUsBtn" style="">...</a>
```

With my config. settings, the `callto:...` value is not recognized as allowed, and so the whole `href` attribute is getting stripped.  I guess I need to override the *type* (<-- or what to call that?) of the `href` value, from `URI` to `CDATA` (?), but do not know how.  I hope there is a quicker/easier way than the directions found here: http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html (if even that would lead to a solution?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Edward's answer, I got it working.

Try this:

In your equivalent of here:
`/htmlpurifier-4_4_0/library/HTMLPurifier/URIScheme/`

add a file named: `callto.php`
...with these contents:

```
<?php

// replicated this class/file from '../htmlpurifier-4_4_0/library/HTMLPurifier/URIScheme/mailto.php'

// VERY RELAXED! Shouldn't cause problems, ... but be careful!

/**
 * Validates 'callto:' phone number in URI to included only alphanumeric, hyphens, underscore, and optional leading "+"
 */

class HTMLPurifier_URIScheme_callto extends HTMLPurifier_URIScheme {

    public $browsable = false;
    public $may_omit_host = true;

    public function doValidate(&$uri, $config, $context) {
        $uri->userinfo = null;
        $uri->host     = null;
        $uri->port     = null;

        /* notes:
            where is the actual phone # parked?  Answer in $uri->path.  See here:

            echo '<pre style="color:pink;">';
            var_dump($uri);
            echo '</pre>';

            object(HTMLPurifier_URI)#490 (7) {
              ["scheme"]=>
              string(6) "callto"
              ["userinfo"]=>
              NULL
              ["host"]=>
              NULL
              ["port"]=>
              NULL
              ["path"]=>
              string(15) "+1-800-555-1212"
              ["query"]=>
              NULL
              ["fragment"]=>
              NULL
            }
        */

        // are the characters in the submitted <a> href's (URI) value (callto:)  from amongst a legal/allowed set?
            // my legal phone # chars:  alphanumeric, underscore, hyphen, optional "+" for the first character.  That's it.  But you can allow whatever you want.  Just change this:
            $validCalltoPhoneNumberPattern = '/^\+?[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/i'; // <---whatever pattern you want to force phone numbers to match
            $proposedPhoneNumber = $uri->path;
            if (preg_match($validCalltoPhoneNumberPattern, $proposedPhoneNumber) !== 1) {
                // submitted phone # inside the href attribute value looks bad; reject the phone number, and let HTMLpurifier remove the whole href attribute on the submitted <a> tag.
                return FALSE;
            } else {
                // submitted phone # inside the href attribute value looks OK; accept the phone number; HTMLpurifier should NOT strip the href attribute on the submitted <a> tag.
                return TRUE;
            }
    }

}
```

...and don't forget to update your HTMLpurifier config., from the default, to include something like this:

```
$config->set('URI.AllowedSchemes', array ('http' => true, 'https' => true, 'mailto' => true, 'ftp' => true, 'nntp' => true, 'news' => true, 'callto' => true,));
```

Comment: Rather than editing the library contents, how do I add my own URIScheme class dynamically? I'm trying this kind of thing: `$urireg = $config->getDefinition('URISchemeRegistry'); $urireg->register(new MyApp_HTMLPurifier_URIScheme_callto, $config);`

Comment: I think I found it: `HTMLPurifier_URISchemeRegistry::instance()->register(new MyApp_HTMLPurifier_URIScheme_callto, $config);`

Comment: Tel support is now provided by default in version 4.8 of HTML Purifier.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a new `HTMLPurifier_URIScheme`. There are plenty of examples in `library/HTMLPurifier/URIScheme`, and it's easy to add custom URI schemes using normal configuration.

Comment: Thanks Edward. I'm in a bit over my head - mostly from being new to OOP & HTMLpurifier. I look in `library/HTMLPurifier/URIScheme` and see the one `abstract class HTMLPurifier_URIScheme`. Are you saying I need to hack that class? I don't see what you mean by "plenty of examples", in there. I updated my config w/: `$config->set('URI.AllowedSchemes', array ('http' => true, ... , 'callto' => true,));`, but apparently still need to "implement a new `HTMLPurifier_URIScheme`" (is that the same as "registering a `HTMLPurifier_URIScheme` to the registry"?).  Can you give me a little more direction?

Comment: There is a URIScheme folder, which contains more files like http.php and ftp.php; those are the examples. The abstract class defines the interface you need to define.

Comment: ahh..  how silly of me.  Yes, the *folder* named `library/HTMLPurifier/URIScheme`.  Thanks so much.  I believe I have done the needful.  (Seems to be working fine.)   I'll post a complete answer to make it easy for the newbies.  If I can be the middle man between your skill/knowledge and the beginners who are even greener than I, than that seems the most useful way to end this post/thread, huh?  How about you comment or vote up on the answer that I will post now... and if I later see that you approve, then I will accept that answer, so it is clear for future readers.  OK?